# Como encontrar un valor en array que ya existe

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo un inconveniente, tengo un array `$resultado[0]` contiene lo siguiente:

```
05:00,04:00,03:00
```

Estos valores separados por comas se extraen de un campo en base de datos, o sea, son los que están registrados en ese campo. ¿Cómo logro para que cuando busque en ese array me indique que ese registro ya esta registrado? Ejemplo, cuando voy a registrar `03:00`, me indique que no se puede por que ya existe ese registro y no pueden haber 2 iguales.

he tratado de extraer primero los registros del array para luego buscar el duplicado pero no me a funcionado, este es el código.

```
$array = array($resultado[0]);

$indice = array_search("05:00" , "04:00" , "03:00" , $array,false);

echo "El número 5 está en el índice: " . $indice . "<br";
```

Para explicar de otra forma es así: En un campo llamado `hora` tengo estos registros `02:00,03:00,04:00` ¿Cómo hago para que en un próximo registro se detecte que no se puede repetir la misma? O sea que el registro ya existe y no se puede duplicar.

Muchas gracias quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error está en la primera línea. Recibes una cadena en `$resultado[0]`. Hacer esto:

```
$array = array($resultado[0]);
```

No extraerá cada ítem que tienes. Retornará un array con un solo elemento, que es la cadena completa.

Lo que debes hacer es utilizar [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) y así obtener los ítems, separados por comas, que contienen la cadena.

```
$array = explode(",", $resultado[0]);
```

Otra manera de hacerlo, sin usar `array_search()`, la puedes ver en este [snippet](https://paiza.io/projects/3CKtTqG8DJG5JXGKJAua4g).

Comment: Gracias, Jonatan te comento, yo tenia el explode naturalmente, pero lo tenia de esta forma:    $resultado = explode(" ", $repetidos);  si puedes observar no le había colocado la coma entre las comillas, yo pensaba que como la cadena tenia comas entonces se asumían pero no, muchas gracias he resulto. :)

Answer (score 1):

Segun entiendo , en esta variable `$resultado[0]` tienes la cadena `05:00,04:00,03:00` y que cuando intentas buscar con el 'array_search' no te lo encuentra , es asi ?

Si es asi , pues a la variable `$resultado[0]` tienes que cortala en bloques de cadena con `explode` que es una funcion de PHP , la cual cortara tu cadena y te devolvera un nuevo arreglo de datos pero separados por coma o cualquier cosa que le pases como argumento , y con el nuevo arreglo puedes hacer uso de la funcion `array_search` que buscara en tu arreglo el valor que desees buscar, antes no lo encontraba porque lo buscaba en una cadena y no en un arreglo .

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que apartes en arreglos los valores de base de datos y los valores que nos servirán de búsqueda.

Lo siguiente sería recorrer cada uno de los elementos buscados y compararlos contra el arreglo de resultados de BD.

```
$resultado[] = "05:00,04:00,03:00";

$a_busqueda = array("05:00" , "04:00" , "03:00");

$a_resultado = explode(",", $resultado[0]);


foreach($a_busqueda as $key => $busqueda)
{
    if(in_array($busqueda, $a_resultado))
    {
        echo "El valor {$busqueda} está en el índice {$key}.<br/>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
El valor 05:00 está en el índice 0.
El valor 04:00 está en el índice 1.
El valor 03:00 está en el índice 2.
```

Espero te sirva